# Compute the residue of the quotient $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ at $a$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $f,g \in H(D(a;r))$ and assume that $f$ has a zero of order $m$ and $g$ a zero of order $m+1$ at $a$. Prove that
>   $$\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}, a\right)=(m+1)\frac{f^{(m)}(a)}{g^{(m+1)}(a)}$$

What I did first was writing

$$f(z)=\frac{h_1(z)}{(z-a)^m} \; g(z)=\frac{h_2(z)}{(z-a)^m}$$
where both $h_1, h_2$ are holomorphic on the open disc and $h_1(a)\neq 0, h_2(a)\neq 0$. Then, by the Cauchy Formula for derivatives

$$\begin{align*}
(m+1)\frac{f^{(m)}(a)}{g^{(m+1)}(a)} &= (m+1) \frac{\frac{m!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(a;r/2)}\frac{h_1(z)}{(z-a)^{m+1}} dz }{\frac{(m+1)!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(a;r/2)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{m+2}} dz}\\
&= \frac{(m+1)!}{(m+1)!}\int_{\gamma(a;r/2)}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} dz\\
&= \int_{\gamma(a;r/2)} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} dz\\
&= 2\pi i\cdot \mathrm{Res} \left( \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} ; a\right)
\end{align*}$$
so I get and extra factor $2\pi i$ and I don't know what I did wrong. Any help would be great with that.

Comment: You're off to a rocky start there. $f(z) = h_1(z)(z-a)^m,$ same for $g$ but you want $m+1$ there. Later there's a weird thing where the quotient of integrals equals the integral of the quotient?

Comment: @zhw. I just realized I wrote it for poles of order $m$ and $m+1$ instead of zeros... Also, the thing with the quotients of integrals...well, not my finest day it seems. By the way, you're answer is great, thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't follow what you're doing. Me, I would let $f(z) = (z-a)^m(c_m + c_{m+1}(z-a) +\cdots),$ $ g(z) = (z-a)^{m+1}(d_{m+1}+ d_{m+2}(z-a)+ \cdots),$ where $c_m, d_{m+1} \ne 0.$ Thus for $z$ near $a,z\ne a,$

$$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{1}{z-a}\cdot \frac{c_m + c_{m+1}(z-a) +\cdots}{d_{m+1} +d_{m+2}(z-a)+ \cdots} = \frac{1}{z-a}\cdot h(z).$$

Now $h$ is the quotient of holomorhic functions that are both nonzero at $a,$ so $h(z)$ extends to be holomorphic near $a,$ with $h(z) = h(a) + h'(a)(z-a) + \cdots$ there. So

$$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{h(a)}{z-a} + h'(a) + \cdots.$$

Thus the residue of $f/g$ at $a$ is $h(a) = c_{m}/d_{m+1}.$ Since $c_m,d_{m+1}$ are Taylor coefficients of $f,g,$ we get the result.